# Given the octagon $ABCDEFGH$, with $\angle GHA=\angle ABC=\angle CDE=\angle EFG=120^o$, $AE\perp GC$ and $AO=OE=OG=OC$, find the area of the octagon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, area

Given the octagon $ABCDEFGH$,  with $\angle GHA=\angle ABC=\angle CDE=\angle EFG=120^o$, $AE\perp GC$ and $AO=OE=OG=OC$ find the area of the octagon.

[image]

We have that $\triangle AGH, \triangle GFE, \triangle DEC, \triangle CBA$ isosceles. $ACEG$ is a square with side $2$. $\angle HGA=\angle HAG=\angle BAC=\angle BCA=\angle DCE=\angle DEC=\angle GEF=\angle EGF$.

Also we have that $HBDF$ is a square. Basically all you need to work out is $GH$, but I can't work it out. Could you please explain to me how to solve the question?

Comment: Another way to go is to recognise that the isosceles triangles, eg ABC, are made up of two 30-60-90 triangles and therefore have sides in the ratio 1:2:√3

Comment: Drop a perp from $H$ to $AG$. It divides $AG$ into half - which is $1$. So height is $1 \cdot \tan 30^0 = 1 / \sqrt3$ and area of $\triangle AGH$ is $1 / \sqrt3$. There are $4$ triangles like that. Subtract that area from the area of the square and that should give you the octagon area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this symmetrical figure, focus on  $\triangle AOK$ , $\triangle ABK$,$\triangle AOB$.

For the simpliticy of calulation, first let us assume  BK=1 $\to$AB=2,AK=OK=$\sqrt 3$:

\begin{align} \frac{S_{ABCDEFGH}}{S_{ACEG}} =\frac{S_{\triangle AOB}}{S_{\triangle AOK}}=\frac{S_{\triangle AOK}-S_{\triangle ABK}}{S_{\triangle AOK}}=1-\frac{S_{\triangle ABK}}{S_{\triangle AOK}}=1-\frac{BK}{OK}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{align}

Now  scale back with $S_{ACEG}=4$, $S_{ABCDEFGH}$=
4$(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$

[image]